# Probability of getting a bingo pattern with a certain number of balls drawn?

Tags: probability, gambling

Let's say you have a fixed pattern on a standard 5x5 bingo card using all the standard bingo rules (center is a free space, B column has numbers 1-15, I has 16-30, etc. to 75). How can you calculate the probability of matching *at least* that pattern in X balls drawn? You can have other spots marked too.

Specifically I'm looking for the odds of hitting the [hot dog pattern](http://www.bingo-lingo.net/images/hotdog.gif) in 17 ball draws, but I'd like to know the method in order to generalize this.

Does the probability depend on the number of cards in play?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $10$ non-free squares in your pattern. There are $\binom{65}{7}$ ways to draw the remaining $7$ balls from the remaining $65$ balls, and $\binom{75}{17}$ ways in total to draw $17$ balls from $75$ balls, so the probability is

$$
\frac{\binom{65}7}{\binom{75}{17}}=\frac{65!\cdot17!}{75!\cdot7!}=\frac{104}{4432786665}\approx2.3\cdot10^{-8}\;.
$$